# Android Fused Location Provider classes not found

Tags: android, android-location

Google revealed new Fused location provider API in [I/O 2013](http://youtu.be/Bte_GHuxUGc?t=15m48s).
I want to change my code based on this new feature. However, my compiler doesn't find **LocationClient** class. I searched [the references](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) and didn't find this class.

My SDK is fully update (Android SDK Tools 22, Android SDK Platform-Tools 17, Android SDK Build Tools 17).

So, Where is this class? Is there any sample about this new API?
Any comments/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you maybe forgotten import the lib

Comment: Exactly. Thanks minjie, Last time I copied Google play services in root of my directory and I had forgotten to replace it with new one. Thanks ;)